# Call unmanaged code permission on desktop app

Tags: c#, .net, clr, native

Does .NET CLR Security perform stack walks to be sure that caller has permission to call unmanaged code even if it is desktop app that runs in full trust?

Comment: I'd imagine so but maybe this will help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677170.aspx

Comment: Of course, you couldn't implement a sandbox if this wasn't the case.  Pre-empting the next question: no, link demands are cheap.  They are only checked once.

Comment: @HansPassant
Thanks I worried more by it's performance impact than thet there is one. Whould you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

No. see [this msdn article about Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tk9z76.aspx)

Quote:

> Full-trust applications are not affected by code access security unless they are marked as security-transparent, because they are fully trusted